# Getting ClassCastException while deploying JAX-WS project to Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, jax-ws

I have created a simple hello world app looking at some simple JAXWS tutorials. But when I try to deploy it on tomcat, I get java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet.
I have already added the required libs to tomcat lib folder.

I tried to look into what might be the issue, and got to know that WSServlet does implement from jakarta servlet family hence I have already added jakarta servlet api libs as well in my tomcat lib folder. Still getting the same issue. Can someone please help.

Note:- Project runs perfectly on tomcat 6.0.x version but gives this error on 8.5.x version.

Here's my project structure for ref.

[image]

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:990)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4952)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5266)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)